# Evaluation board for side channel attacks

Tags: cryptography, hardware, ecc, side-channel

I have started working on side channel attacks particularly focusing on DPA and DEMA for different cryptographic algorithms; targeting FPGA devices. I want to measure the power and EM radiated out of FPGA while crypto algorithm is running. In order to achieve the purpose, one way is to add circuitry to the existing FPGA boards and other is to work with ready made evaluation board that is already designed for side channel analysis. Definitely that is going to save me time and I can focus on my research thing. I want to go for option 2 without getting into electronics stuff. Now, I have found these; DPA workstation, Inspector, SASEBO (SAkura), FOBOS and Chip Whisperer.I want evaluation board for my student level research project and for obvious reasons, it should not be expensive. Below are my Queries regarding selection of evaluation board for side channel analysis.

1. I am looking for a cheaper solution that can be used for side channel analysis providing same facilities as SASEBO. I have seen FOBOS and Chip Whisperer. Though I am unable to find proper support for former one while later one has alot of documentation and variety of boards available. If I go for chip whisperer, will the connectivity be smooth for CW1173 ChipWhisperer-Lite and Xilinx Virtex-7 board?
2. Is there any other such (low cost) side channel analysis specific evaluation board having Virtex-7 for student level project?
3. If I go for SASEBO(which is quiet expensive), Can I change the crypto algorithms on Kintex of SASEBO GIII(now known as SAKURA-X)? Can it easily be customized according to my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If looking to use off-the-shelf boards, you can potentially use the H-Field probe solution. See https://wiki.newae.com/H_Probe_Usage for an example of H-Probe usage, there are lots of standard COTS probes/amplifiers around.

We've also got a FPGA target board that "just works" with ChipWhisperer, see https://wiki.newae.com/CW305_Artix_FPGA_Target . It's similar to various other FPGA boards, it's using Artix 7.

Any of the FPGA boards let you customize the crypto, of course though it may be some work to implement your algorithm.

Comment: Please disclose your relationship with the links that you provide. You appear to work for NewAE.

Comment: I do sorry - I'm not claiming those links are anything you need to buy though (H-Field probes are the same from any vendor as mentioned) & wasn't claiming to be objective in my wording, so was leaving it as implied. Will be more clear for future links.

Comment: The problem is more about using StackExchange to drive traffic to your site. Your links are wikis (and not sales pages) so I left them. But do disclose in the future.